# Class property not supported by object

Tags: class, vbscript, properties

I have the beginning of a Class which will ultimatly be used to create, check and delete check-files.

The below code seems correct based on the resources I have found, but when I run it I'm presented with an error on line 4 -

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Names'

What am I doning wrong here?

```
Dim CheckFile
Set CheckFile = new ManageCheckFile

Call CheckFile.Names("chkfile", Array("bucf", "id"), "20150618")

Class ManageCheckFile

    Private m_cfNames
    Private m_cfPrefix
    Private m_cfTypes
    Private m_cfDate

    '**
     ' Set the cfNames property
     ' Also set the cfPrefix, cfTypes and cfDate properties
     '*
    Public Property Let Names(prefix, types, date)

        m_cfPrefix = prefix
        m_cfTypes = types
        m_cfDate = date
        Dim i   ' Dummy for looping
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_cfTypes)
            m_cfNames(i) = m_cfPrefix & "-" & m_cfDate & "." & m_cfTypes(i)
        Next

    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I don't think you can `Call` a `Property`. It seems like what you actually want is a `Sub`, not a `Property`. I would go with `Public Sub SetNames(...)`.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now.  You can only use `Let` \ `Set` to pass a single variable to the property, and I should be using `=` to set the property, not treating it like a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are used like variables, even though they're defined like procedures. You can't call properties (the [`Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5%28v=vs.84%29) keyword only works for procedures and functions). Instead you assign values to them like this:

```
object.property = value
```

Also, VBScript allows only a single value to be assigned to a property. The other parameters to property getters and setters are intended for index access. A property defined like this:

```
Property Let Foo(a, b, c)
```

must be used like this:

```
object.Foo(valueA, valueB) = valueC
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77kezfet%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> ```
> [Public | Private] Property Let name ([arglist,] value)
>    [statements]
>    [Exit Property] 
>    [statements]
> End Property
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> *arglist*
>
> List of variables representing arguments that are passed to the **Property Let** procedure when it is called. Commas separate multiple arguments. The name of each argument in a **Property Let** procedure must be the same as the corresponding argument in a **Property Get** procedure. In addition, the **Property Let** procedure will always have one more argument than its corresponding **Property Get** procedure. That argument is the value being assigned to the property.

If you must assign multiple values to one property, you need to wrap the values in an appropriate data structure (an array, a dictionary, a custom object, etc.). Example:

```
Class ManageCheckFile
    Private m_cfNames
    Private m_cfPrefix
    Private m_cfTypes
    Private m_cfDate

    Public Property Let Names(data)
        m_cfPrefix = data("prefix")
        m_cfTypes  = data("types")
        m_cfDate   = data("date")

        Dim i
        ReDim m_cfNames(UBound(m_cfTypes))
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_cfTypes)
            m_cfNames(i) = m_cfPrefix & "-" & m_cfDate & "." & m_cfTypes(i)
        Next
    End Property
End Class

Set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
values.Add "prefix", "chkfile"
values.Add "types", Array("bucf", "id")
values.Add "date", "20150618"

Set CheckFile = New ManageCheckFile
CheckFile.Names = values
```

Or you use an actual method for populating multiple member variables:

```
Class ManageCheckFile
    Private m_cfNames
    Private m_cfPrefix
    Private m_cfTypes
    Private m_cfDate

    Public Sub Names(prefix, types, date)
        m_cfPrefix = prefix
        m_cfTypes  = types
        m_cfDate   = date

        Dim i
        ReDim m_cfNames(UBound(m_cfTypes))
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_cfTypes)
            m_cfNames(i) = m_cfPrefix & "-" & m_cfDate & "." & m_cfTypes(i)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Set CheckFile = New ManageCheckFile
CheckFile.Names "chkfile", Array("bucf", "id"), "20150618"
```

If you make it the default method of the class and have it return the object you can (sort of) initialize the object right after its creation:

```
Class ManageCheckFile
    Private m_cfNames
    Private m_cfPrefix
    Private m_cfTypes
    Private m_cfDate

    Public Default Function Names(prefix, types, date)
        m_cfPrefix = prefix
        m_cfTypes  = types
        m_cfDate   = date

        Dim i
        ReDim m_cfNames(UBound(m_cfTypes))
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_cfTypes)
            m_cfNames(i) = m_cfPrefix & "-" & m_cfDate & "." & m_cfTypes(i)
        Next

        Set Names = Me
    End Function
End Class

Set CheckFile = (New ManageCheckFile)("chkfile", Array("bucf", "id"), "20150618")
```

Another option might be to use `prefix` and `date` as the *arglist* parameters:

```
Class ManageCheckFile
    Private m_cfNames
    Private m_cfPrefix
    Private m_cfTypes
    Private m_cfDate

    Public Property Let Names(prefix, date, types)
        m_cfPrefix = prefix
        m_cfDate   = date
        m_cfTypes  = types

        Dim i
        ReDim m_cfNames(UBound(m_cfTypes))
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_cfTypes)
            m_cfNames(i) = m_cfPrefix & "-" & m_cfDate & "." & m_cfTypes(i)
        Next
    End Property

    Public Property Get Names(prefix, date)
        Names = m_cfNames
    End Property
End Class

Set CheckFile = New ManageCheckFile
CheckFile.Names("chkfile", "20150618") = Array("bucf", "id")
```

However, that doesn't make much sense unless `prefix` and `date` actually do index something, which doesn't seem to be the case here. With what I've seen from your code I'd probably go either the data structure or the default method route.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing you might better be served by a Function than a Class.  You don't want to go with a Sub if you want it to return anything.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx